# Fractional, first-order correction to a physical quantity via Taylor Series

Tags: general-relativity, perturbation-theory, calculus

I am currently reading a GR paper and I'm stuck on this particular point of that paper. It says:

> Let $q_0$ denote a physical quantity in the unperturbed $(S = 0)$ orbit and $q^*$ denote a fractional, first-order spin-induced correction to that quantity:
> $$
> q^*\equiv \frac{1}{q_0}\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial S}\right)_{S=0}
> $$
> $$
> q^*=\frac{\delta q}{q_{0}S}+ O(S^2)
> $$
> The physical quantity $q$ is the given by
> $$
> q=q_0(1+S q^*)
> $$

Given that I know the exact expression for $q_{0}$, how can I obtain the first-order correction $q^{*}$?

I am lost with how to make sense of the given definition. I imagine the last equation as some sort of ansatz or the first two terms of the Taylor series of the quantity $q$ around $S=0$, and then plug it into an expression to obtain $q^{*}$. I think this is a general question, but I am missing something.

Comment: Which GR paper? Which page?

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960104006711. It's on the 2nd page.

Comment: It then proceeds to considering a specific $q$ which is $\Omega$, and the paper obtained the corresponding first-order correction $\Omega^*$ in eq. (9) which I don't know how to derive.